# Getting error in ANT regex "Couldn't rename temporary file C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\replace7877977241325466040.txt"

Tags: regex, ant, temp

In ANT, I am trying to replace a file's property using regex  by using the below script:

```
<property file="MyFilePath/MyFileName1.properties" />
<replaceregexp file="MyFilePath/MyFileName2.properties"
   match="@{ComparingProperties}=(.*)"
   replace="@{ComparingProperties}=${@{ComparingProperties}}" />
```

Read a content from MyFileName1 and replacing the property in MyFileName2.

While execution I am facing issue as `"Couldn't rename temporary file C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\replace7877977241325466040.txt"`

If I remove this regex and try, the build goes fine. In many of my scripts I used replaceregex, but this is the place I get this error newly. Any inputs would be really helpful. Thanks !

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34633